# How to set a thumbnail as extension in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: registry, thumbnails, file-extension, regedit

I know how to register an extension with Icon and more in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, but how to use something like this:

`Thumbnail` instead of `DefaultIcon`

I need for register an thumbnail extension for an installer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `DefaultIcon` only set static icons.

> Thumbnails are a piece of image that are displayed instead of icons

Short answer is simple: Thumbnails are readed from file, not from registry, so, use your favourite icon in `DefaultIcon` and let your file was the dependent of thumbnails